# Round sum of decimal column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using this code to sum decimal values.

```
SUM(Amount) as TotalAmount
```

Amount column is decimal datatype

```
Amount decimal (10,4)
```

After summing up the columns I get values like this

```
13500.8765
12005.0000
```

My expected output should be like this

```
13501
12005
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The ROUND() function is used to round a numeric field to the number of decimals specified.

Syntax:

```
SELECT ROUND(column_name,decimals) FROM table_name;
```

For your problem, try this:

```
CONVERT(int,ROUND(SUM(Amount),0)) as TotalAmount --Converting to int to remove the fractional part
```

Read more about `ROUND` [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx).

Comment: I have to show a round off value, the .0000 shouldn't be displayed.

Comment: For the query I have given, it would result the rounded value without .0000

Comment: But I see .0000 getting displayed.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to round and remove the fractional part you can simply CAST it to a DECIMAL with different precision:

```
select cast(SUM(Amount) as DECIMAL(18,0)) as TotalAmount
```

Answer (score 4):

[Round](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx)

```
ROUND(SUM(Amount),0) as TotalAmount
```

## [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69b77/1)

Comment: yes I get the round off values, but how can I remove the dot and numbers after that (.0000)--> I need to remove this.

Comment: This query wont give you .0000 @user3279082

Answer (score 2):

```
select ROUND(SUM(Amount),0) as TOTALAmount from tableName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @A DECIMAL(13,5)
DECLARE @B DECIMAL(13,5)
SET @A = 156.221212
SET @B = 156.821212

SELECT CAST(@A+@B AS INT)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use the (10,4) you actually saying that you want a total of 10 digits, 4 of them after the decimal point, so you can try something like (10,0).

Answer (score 0):

The following should be the correct expression to SUM decimal values:

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(CONVERT(FLOAT, Field8)) AS NVARCHAR(255)) 
FROM Session1 
WHERE Field1='[*0*]';​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  CAST(ROUND(15.09,0)as decimal(18,0)) as RoundNo
```

Use this, I hope that it is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
select cast(SUM(Amount) as INT) as TotalAmount
```